# Why I get different predictions from same neural-network model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, prediction

As the title I wrote, I stuck in the problem that my neural network makes different prediction values.

Here is the steps I did to get predictions using neural network.

First, normalized x and made neural network model using 'nnet'.

After, I made predictions using predict command. predict(nnet model, test data)

But the problem is, I got the different predictions whenever I run neural network.

For example,

mymodel<-nnet(~~~~)

predict(mymodel.test data)

I got the value A from prediction.

After, I did the same command 'mymodel<-nnet(~~~~) predict(mymodel.test data)' again, then it's natural that I get the A for prediction value. But at this time, I got B.

If I run it again, I got C.

Why I get the different predictions from same neural network model?

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The only way to answer this is wit code, which you need to provide. A self-containing example that shows the problem would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you are re-training your model before making another prediction. Training a neural network model by default involves setting the each neuron value some random values on initialization. Therefore, each training would produce different models up to some degree.

To avoid that, either use the same model instance (only execute `mymodel<-nnet(~~~~)` once at the beginning and keep executing only `predict()` afterwards), or set a seed for random value generation, so that you always get the same set of random values being initialized

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting different results even though the data and model are the same is because every time you ask for a prediction your asking the program to initialize everything the model would need (i.e the weights). If you want the same results each time then you need to keep the same values for the weights and not reinitialize them each time, you could do this by putting them in a Data Base for later use